# VHDL XST signal warning

Tags: signals, warnings, vhdl

Im makian a vhdl project and im getting this warning:
Its a small aplication displaying 2 letters on the 8x8 matrix display.

```
    WARNING:Xst:819 - "C:/fitkitSVN/apps/demo/xhrbot01/fpga/ledc8x8.vhd" line 114: One or more signals are missing in the process sensitivity list. To enable synthesis of FPGA/CPLD hardware, XST will assume that all necessary signals are present in the sensitivity list. Please note that the result of the synthesis may differ from the initial design specification. The missing signals are:
   <switch>, <single_row>
```

This is the process on the line 114

```
-- Display lines 
    display_lines: process (row_counter)
    begin
        ROW <= row_counter;
        if switch /= '1' then
            LED <= "11111111";
        else
            LED <= single_row;
        end if;
    end process;
----------------
```

And there are signal declarations used in this process

```
-- Indent of row
signal row_counter: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 to 7) := "10000000";

-- One row
signal single_row: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 to 7);

-- Switch using for displaying correct row 
signal switch: STD_LOGIC;
```

Could anyone tell me how to remove the warning and why is this warning displaying?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look at the content of your process:

```
    ROW <= row_counter;
    if switch /= '1' then
        LED <= "11111111";
    else
        LED <= single_row;
    end if;
```

What signals are being used here? I can see `row_counter`, `switch`, and `single_row` being used either as the source of an assignment, or in a condition clause. Now look at your sensitivity list:

```
row_counter
```

You have only told the process to be sensitive to changes of this one signal, and yet your process actually depends on two other signals as well. This is what the warning means.

---

Most synthesis tools ignore the sensitivity list, and generate the same hardware either way. However, most simulators will not. This can result in confusing differences between what your design does in a simulator, and what it does in the real hardware.

If your tool chain supports it, you can create an automatic sensitivity list by replacing the list with the keyword `all`. So you would have something like `process (all)`.